# Classifying pandas columns according to range limits

Tags: pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dataframe with several numeric columns and their range goes either from `1 to 5` or `1 to 10`

I want to create two lists of these columns names this way:

```
names_1to5 = list of all columns in df with numbers ranging from 1 to 5


names_1to10 = list of all columns in df with numbers from 1 to 10
```

Example:

```
IP  track  batch  size  type
1    2      3     5      A
9    1      2     8      B
10   5      5     10     C
```

from the dataframe above:

```
  names_1to5 = ['track', 'batch']
  names_1to10 = ['ip', 'size']
```

I want to use a function that gets a dataframe and perform the above transformation only on columns with numbers within those ranges.

I know that if the column 'max()' is `5` than it's `1to5` same idea when `max() is 10`

**What I already did:**

```
def test(df):
    list_1to5 = []
    list_1to10 = []
    
    for col in df:
        if df[col].max() == 5:
            list_1to5.append(col)
        else:
            list_1to10.append(col)
    return list_1to5, list_1to10
```

I tried the above but it's returning the following error msg:

```
'>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

The type of the columns is 'object' maybe this is the reason. If this is the reason, how can I fix the function without the need to cast these columns to float as there are several, sometimes hundreds of these columns and if I run:

`df['column'].max()` I get `10` or `5`

What's the best way to create this this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
string = """alpha IP  track  batch  size
A   1    2      3     5
B   9    1      2     8
C   10   5      5     10"""

temp = [x.split() for x in string.split('\n')]
cols = temp[0]
data = temp[1:]

def test(df):
    list_1to5 = []
    list_1to10 = []
    
    for col in df.columns:
        if df[col].dtype!='O':
            if df[col].max() == 5:
                list_1to5.append(col)
            else:
                list_1to10.append(col)
    return list_1to5, list_1to10

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = cols, dtype=float)
```

Output:

```
(['track', 'batch'], ['IP', 'size'])
```

Comment: Thanks man.  The code is not working because df has columns with strings too.  When the code find these columns and returns `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'A'` How can I skip these string columns?  I updated the working example.  my bad.

Comment: Look at the answer now.